# Error when declaring a recursive function with default parameter in C++

Tags: function, recursion, declaration

Firstly, I would like to say that I'm a beginner in C++ and on StackOverflow as well, I'm open to critique and advice.

*Now to the main issue*, I'm messing with recursion and I wrote the code below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; //not best practice, but it was supposed to be a quick test

unsigned long long sum_range(unsigned long long, unsigned long long = 0); //most likely the issue

int main(){
    unsigned long long result = sum_range(100); 
    cout << result << endl;
}

unsigned long long sum_range(unsigned long long range, unsigned long long current = 0){ //it works if i put the actual funcition's code above the main()
    /*
    This is a basic recursive function that returns the sum of all the number within the specified range. 
    range : it is the last value of the range, being 0-{value of "range"}, it includes the value of range in the sum.
    current : this is the variable that stores the sum throughout the recursion.
    */
    if (range == 0){
        return current;
    }
    else{
        current += range;
        return sum_range(--range, current=current);
    }
}
```

To me, the code above seems fine, but when i try to compile with g++ this error appears:

```
>>> g++ -o test.exe test.cpp

test.cpp:11:20: error: default argument given for parameter 2 of 'long long unsigned int sum_range(long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int)' [-fpermissive]
   11 | unsigned long long sum_range(unsigned long long range, unsigned long long current = 0){ //it seems to work, if i put the actual funcition above the main()
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:4:20: note: previous specification in 'long long unsigned int sum_range(long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int)' here
    4 | unsigned long long sum_range(unsigned long long, unsigned long long = 0); //most likely the issue
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~
```

But I can't figure out what's wrong, as commented in the code above, I tried to put the function's code above main() and it worked, which makes me believe that the problem is with this declaration:

`unsigned long long sum_range(unsigned long long, unsigned long long = 0);`

I also tried to reformat it like this:

`unsigned long long sum_range(unsigned long long range , unsigned long long current = 0);`

still, the same error and I got stuck, I don't have the slightest clue on how to fix it, so I'm hoping someone could clarify what's the issue here.

Comment: You have the `= 0` default value of the argument in the declaration of the function, so remove it from the definition of the function..

Comment: Do you mean make the declaration "unsigned long long sum_range(unsigned long long, unsigned long long);", if it was what you meant it still causes an error, but this time the issue is that the main calls a function that is supposed to have 2 params, but it only gives one.

Comment: What I meant is remove `= 0` from the line `//it works if`.